# get values from array in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, angular-datatables

i want to retrieve values from array my code is like

```
this.RoleServiceService.getRoleById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.roleData.push(data['data']);
  console.log(this.roleData);
})
```

but i am getting array like this

i have tried like  `role=roleData[0];` but giving undefined can you please help me with this
[image]

```
    []
0
:
Array(4)
0
:
{id: 5, name: "edit_page", guard_name: "api", created_at: "2018-03-30 10:09:38", updated_at: "2018-03-30 10:09:38", …}
1
:
{id: 6, name: "create_page", guard_name: "api", created_at: "2018-03-30 10:09:38", updated_at: "2018-03-30 10:09:38", …}
2
:
{id: 7, name: "create_post", guard_name: "api", created_at: "2018-04-06 11:11:40", updated_at: "2018-04-06 11:11:40", …}
3
:
{id: 8, name: "view_post", guard_name: "api", created_at: "2018-04-06 11:11:40", updated_at: "2018-04-06 11:11:40", …}
length
:
4
```

Comment: you want to acess from which array?

Comment: try  console.log(this.roleData[0])

Comment: i wan to access from roleData

Comment: @AlexFF1 tried but giving undefined

Comment: what is `data['data']`? This looks illogical

Comment: try `this.roleData.push('data');` and check this in console

Comment: i am getting array in data['data']

Comment: can you show, how you are getting array in `data['data']`.

Comment: try 'console.log(data['data'])' and tell what it returns

Comment: @WASIF data['data'] === data.data if data has property called data, eg: let data = { data: 'asdf' }

Comment: you should call something like this `data.data` instead of `data['data']`

Comment: Can you post the code for trying to access the array? Can you show the structure of the objects in your array by toggling them open in the console. It looks like you are trying to access a property that doesn't exist.

Comment: ok i will updated the question

Comment: @WASIF calling an object with ['propName'] is perfectly valid

Comment: @floor thanks, you recall my knowledge

Comment: @PranavMandlik can you post what you have when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(this.roleData));

Comment: @PranavMandlik great for adding the array now can you explain / show how and what you want out of the array

Comment: ok i want each json array as single row

Comment: actually you can see its starts from [] then it has indexes

Comment: i guess that [] creating problems

Comment: you can see in screenshot also

Comment: @PranavMandlik dont just put the console array. add the json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take, `this.roleData = data['data']`

Since `data['data']` returns an `array`, it is wrong that you are pushing that array to first `index`;

```
this.roleData = [];

this.RoleServiceService.getRoleById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.roleData = data['data'];
  console.log(data['data']);
  console.log(this.roleData);
})
```

If you want to `append the data` you can also use a `for loop`

**Appeding data:**

```
this.RoleServiceService.getRoleById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  data['data'].forEach(element => {
    this.roleData.push(element)
 });
  console.log(data['data']);
  console.log(this.roleData);
})
```

Comment: its giving null array

Comment: in which console you are getting nul

Comment: I mean at what place, you consoled in code? what is the result of the `console.log` I added in answer

Comment: its like
 []
length:0

Comment: and you are `consoling` inside that `subscribe` function right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168642/discussion-between-sravan-and-pranav-mandlik).

Answer (score 0):

this.roleData = data['data'] it's worked form me..maybe the income from someone's treatment